# BLE Beacon vs Peripheral - Which is better for mobile app background scanning?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process

I'm  a firmware developer, and 2 of my clients both have similar needs: they are developing mobile apps that interface with my hardware and open their respective apps when an advertisement is received in the background.

Client A absolutely needs a peripheral, since GATT writes/reads are done for the core functionality of the device.

Client B can use either, as really the only thing they need are advertisements.

Client A has come back with complaints that their mobile app developers are having issues with peripheral advertisements, and would like to switch to a "connectable beacon" (which in my eyes is just a peripheral with modified advertisement data)

Are there any good resources on which works better with Android/iOS background tasks?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "connectable beacon" in iOS. You could have your device act as an Eddystone beacon, but to iOS that is just a Bluetooth peripheral. IBeacons are not connectable; they simply advertise a uuid and two 16 bit numbers. iBeacon requires an iOS app to have location permission from the user while a BLE peripheral (which includes Eddystone) requires Bluetooth permission from the user.

Comment: On iOS once a peripheral is "discovered" they should be storing the reported `identifier` and then issue a `connect`. If the peripheral disconnects they should immediately issue another `connect`. iOS will not report a previously discovered peripheral in the background.  It will, however, automatically complete a pending `Connect` without any further action from the app as long as the app as enabled Bluetooth background and set up Bluetooth state restoration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Client A is expecting to receive the collected data of your peripheral through "asynchronous" callbacks from BluetoothGattCallback class.

From what I could hypothesize, Client A is expecting an onCharacteristicChanged() callback being triggered by a Notification from a previously registered Characteristic, all raised by the BLE device.

Basically, this makes the peripheral data transfer less dependent of the scanning callbacks timming raised by Android itself, and it immediatly receives the data when the device triggers it.